# alternate the elements of an array from the first one to next and print the alternated array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm stuck on an assignment to create a program that:

1. User inputs size of elemnets in array.
2. User inputs the elements themself.
3. Calculate sum of the first element + 2nd, than 1st + 2nd + 3rd etc...
4. Alternate the array with the new values and print it.

For example:
- user inputs: [7,5,-8,3,4]
- output: [7,12,4,7,11]

My code attempts to do this, but not achieving the right result and I think there's something wrong with my array arithmetic. Can anyone help?

Output for the first 4 digits is all over the map: 12, -3, -5....

```
int main () {

    int *arr;
    int i, n;

    printf("Please enter the size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter array values: ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("The alternated array is: \n");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]+arr[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: they problem is they did not read the tutorial on how to use the site

Comment: So each element of your new array needs to be the sum of all the elements up to the corresponding position of your old array... don't you need to add more than two elements for most of those?  Or keep a running total?

Answer (score 1):

Now all you need to do is the following

```
int *arr2 = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

int sum = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
   sum += arr[i];
   arr2[i] = sum;
}
```

and so on.:)

After you will fill the second array you can output it the same way as the first array.

As for this loop

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]+arr[i+1]);
```

then it does not make sense

(

```
printf("The new array is: \n");
```

Where is there the new array?:))

and moreover there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

At the end of the program write

```
free( arr );
free( arr2 );
```

Take into account that you need to split your program into functions.

Comment: Yeah this should work for that.

Comment: my bad, i dont need to print to a new array, i need to alternate the existing array with the new values.